PowerShell command to download GitHub release
Currently I have a private GitHub repo that holds some compressed files in the releases section using the following PowerShell command
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://github.com/Org/repo/releases/download/v1.0.0/file.zip" -Headers @{"Accept" = "application/vnd.github+json"; "Authorization" = "Bearer github_token"; "X-GitHub-Api-Version" = "2022-11-28"}

However when I attempt this I get a 404 error. Does anyone know how I can modify the command above in order to download file.zip
